# Twitter Bootstrap: Divide container into two colours

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not sure how to accomplish this in Bootstrap:
[image: Bootsrap container divided into 2 colours]

I that would be one colour than I would know how to do this.

I only know how to do colours inside container which max width is col-md-12:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 blue"></div>
    <div class="col-md-9 red"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the background color using css, say for the body:

```
background: rgba(52,247,75,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(52,247,75,1) 0%, rgba(52,247,75,1) 38%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 38%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(52,247,75,1)), color-stop(38%, rgba(52,247,75,1)), color-stop(38%, rgba(246,41,12,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(231,56,39,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(52,247,75,1) 0%, rgba(52,247,75,1) 38%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 38%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(52,247,75,1) 0%, rgba(52,247,75,1) 38%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 38%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(52,247,75,1) 0%, rgba(52,247,75,1) 38%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 38%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(52,247,75,1) 0%, rgba(52,247,75,1) 38%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 38%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#34f74b', endColorstr='#e73827', GradientType=1 );
```